# Knowing A and the discriminant, how to find B and C?

Tags: quadratics, discriminant

On a Quadratic equation of the form $ax^2+bx+c$, I am given the discriminant ($\Delta=b^2-4ac$) and **A**.

To find B and C, I tried to solve it through $x1$ and $x2$...:

- $x1 = \frac{-b-\sqrt{\Delta}}{a}$
- $x2 = \frac{-b+\sqrt{\Delta}}{a}$

...using those properties:

- $x1 + x2 = - \frac{b}{a}$
- $x1 \times x2 = \frac{c}{a}$

Without any success...

So, is it possible to retrieve **B** and **C**?

Two additional properties:

- the discriminant is always positive
- B is always negative

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: Don't you think that you could recall that the quadratic equation is $Ax^2+Bx+C=0$ ?

Comment: Answer: No. Details on demand once you have shown that you have worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One equation

$$\Delta=B^2-4AC\tag{1}$$

with 2 unknowns $B$ and $C$: there is a fundamental indeterminacy.

A counterexample among many: If $A=1/4$ and $\Delta=16$, (1) becomes:

$$16=B^2-C$$

which is possible for $(B=-4, \ C=0)$, $(B=-5, \ C=9)$, $(B=-6, \ C=20)$, etc. (I have taken into account the constraint on $B$ to be negative).

Otherwise said,

$$\frac14x^2-4x=0, \ \ \ \frac14x^2-5x+9=0, \ \ \ \frac14x^2-6x+2\sqrt{5}=0$$

have all the same $A$ and the same $\Delta$ without having the same $B$ and the same $C$.

Comment: I computed the $\Delta$ ($b^2-4ac$) for those 3 equations and they don't share the same one

Comment: $\Delta1 = (-4)^2-4\times\frac{1}{4}\times0 = 16$   ,  $\Delta2 = (-5)^2-4\times\frac{1}{4}\times9 = 16$  , $\Delta3 = -6^2-4\times\frac{1}{4}\times2\sqrt5 = 31.52..$

Comment: Now corrected for $\Delta_3$ which is also equal to $20$, etc.

Comment: Thank you! I can see that they all share the $y$ but not for the same $x$.